# Sync wireless passwords between Windows computers

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, sync, passwords

I'm looking for a way to synchronize wireless network passwords between each of the computers I use (to avoid typing each of them more than once.) Is it possible to do this on Windows?

Comment: It's not very hard... how many computers do you have?

Comment: I have 3 computers, and I access multiple wireless networks from each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use the Free Program called "[c't Wlan Kloner](http://www.heise.de/download/ct-wlan-kloner.html)" to export the WiFi-Settings for one Network and Import it back on a other Computer.
The Program itself creates kind of xml-Files with all the required informations in it.

The only downside (for you) that it is only avaliable in german language.